# Excel pivot table filtering

Tags: function, date, pivot-table, formula

I am trying to filter data that was collected within 24 hours from the first collection to the last one. Some are collected 25 hours some are 48 which are irrelevant to me.

Is there a way to make excel recognise data that was collected within 24 hours? and show only those in the next worksheet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored as DateTimes, then if you put the DateTime field in the PivotTable as a RowField, then you  can filter your PivotTable on DateTimes between one DateTime and another DateTime. You just need to type the starting DateTime and the ending DateTime into the DateFilter dialog box, rather than selecting from the calendar.

For instance, below I am filtering a RowField of a PivotTable for the 24 hour period between 9:44:07 AM on 29/07/2017 and 9:44:07 AM on 30/07/2017:

[image]

[image]